# How to change variable to factor based on its name in some list by using across?

Tags: r, tidyverse

(I am new in R)

Trying to change variables data type of df `members` to `factors` based on condition if their names available in a list `to_factors_list`.

I have tried some code using `mutate(across())` but it's giving errors.

**Data prep.:**

```
library(tidyverse)

# tidytuesday himalayan data
members <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/members.csv")

# creating list of names
to_factors_list <- members %>% 
  map_df(~(data.frame(n_distinct = n_distinct(.x))),
        .id = "var_name") %>%
  filter(n_distinct < 15) %>%
  select(var_name) %>% pull()

to_factors_list

############### output ###############
'season''sex''hired''success''solo''oxygen_used''died''death_cause''injured''injury_type'
```

**Getting error in below code attempts:**

```
members %>%
  mutate(across(~.x %in% to_factors_list, factor))
```

```
members %>%
  mutate_if( ~.x %in% to_factors_list, factor)
```

I am not sure what's wrong and how can I make this work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
members %>% mutate(across(to_factors_list, factor))
```

Or if you prefer an older-version `dplyr` syntax:

```
members %>% mutate_at(vars(to_factors_list), factor)
```

Comment: Thanks @ekoam, i thought it would need a conidtion syntax and ended up writing a wrong code. Thanks alot for helping !!

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, this can be done with `lapply`

```
members[to_factors_list] <- lapply(members[to_factors_list], factor)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, this is also very helpful !!